# without inserting the entire project code how to call classes from one project into another project in android

Tags: android

```
01-28 13:51:17.332: D/AndroidRuntime(766): Shutting down VM
01-28 13:51:17.332: W/dalvikvm(766): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.canadaqbank.usmle/com.canadaqbank.usmle.USMLEActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.canadaqbank.usmle.USMLEActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.canadaqbank.usmle-1.apk]
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.canadaqbank.usmle.USMLEActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.canadaqbank.usmle-1.apk]
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 11 more
```

I want to call one project classes into another project without keep all the entire code in this project, I added it in the build path and also declared that class in the manifest file but when I call it gives me a `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class . I am calling it from intent`.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.bank.Header
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.bank.Header
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.bank.us.USActivity.onCreate(USActivity.java:25)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 11 more
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.bank.Header.<init>(Header.java:223)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 21 more
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 10:42:57.503: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 25 more
```

---

Update : - New logcat Error

```
01-28 13:51:17.332: D/AndroidRuntime(766): Shutting down VM
01-28 13:51:17.332: W/dalvikvm(766): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bank.us/com.bank.us.USActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bank.us.USActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.bank.us-1.apk]
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.canadaqbank.usmle.USMLEActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.canadaqbank.usmle-1.apk]
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
01-28 13:51:17.522: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting another project's activity then you can do it by this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                "com.abc.def.packname",
                "com.abc.def.packname.MyActivity"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I add the above code....Now it showing this error    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: @sandy Please post the new logcat output. And make sure you have added property android:exported="true" in another activity's manifest file.

Comment: @sandy Please add this in your question only.

Comment: i keep that code into the my java file logcat displays the above mentioned error,Please help me....

Comment: @sandy Did u add property android:exported="true" for activity USActivity in manifest?

Comment: i want to call more packages in one project, Is this code for calling all the other projects..Please suggest me....

Comment: @sandy This code is to call an activity of other project which is installed in the phone/emulator already.

Comment: I want to call more packages in one project,without installing the other projects in the emulator/phone.want single apk generated by all the projects...please help me...

Comment: @sandy I dont think that would be possible. The package must be available in phone/ emulator to refer it